# How to convert hdmi to vga output in raspberrypi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

Hi  i am  trying to  convert output hdmi to VGA   from raspberrypi i am able to achieve this  but  when i do  this my screen from left  and right side  show some blank screen how can i remove this blank screen from left and right

i used following setting

```
disable_overscan=1
framebuffer_width=768
framebuffer_height=1280
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=23
hdmi_drive=2
config_hdmi_boost=4
```

How can i achieve my output

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Either remove the following line or comment it out.

```
disable_overscan=1
```

or

```
#disable_overscan=1
```

Comment: How did u fixed ur this problem

Comment: I commented out disable_overscan=1 

If this didn't work for you try changing the value in hdmi_group and hdmi_mode.